# What is the difference between global cache and distributed cache? When are they used?

Tags: caching, system

I read this on Grokking the System Design Interview:

*If the request layer is expanded to multiple nodes, it’s still quite possible to have each node host its own cache. However, if your load balancer randomly distributes requests across the nodes, the same request will go to different nodes, thus increasing cache misses. Two choices for overcoming this hurdle are global caches and distributed caches.*

Can someone help explain What is the difference between global cache and distributed cache? When are they used? Thanks.